# Is it possible to create database or delete database in rds using spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I want to know that how we perform create and delete db operation using spring boot in aws rds sql db

I have tried application.properties to add new db config but it doesn’t work.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://your-rds-endpoint:3306/your-database-name
spring.datasource.username=your-username
spring.datasource.password=your-password
```

Comment: What steps are you taking to run your code? What are you expecting to happen? What errors are you seeing?